# How to use SqlBulkCopy with transaction on ReliableSqlConnection in sql azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, transactions, sqlbulkcopy

Our application on azure cloud service,
 We need to perform some operations on sql azure using the same transaction,  (insert into and SqlBulkCopy) using  ReliableSqlConnection to allow Transaction.Rollback If any steps fail

but  run this code:
 using (SqlBulkCopy ContactsDistBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(oConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, oTransaction))

Ask for system.data.connection and not ReliableSqlConnection  ?

Answer (score 1):

How much data are you passing in Bulk?   You might be able to use a Table-Valued-Parameter approach instead of Bulk Copy, and that is simple to include in a transaction.   The table you assemble on the client is sent to SQL as a parameter very quickly, and inserts are performed with BULK optimizations on the server.  This is appropriate for ~O(10000) rows.   This would fit into the ReliableSQLConnection framework, as long as you use the rsc.ExecuteCommand style of invoking the command.

You can find more details at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: Between 10K to 100k rows

Comment: you can send it in chunks of 10k

Answer (score 0):

`SqlBulkCopy` only supports `SqlConnection`. This bulk insert mechanism simply requires SQL Server to work. It cannot work with an arbitrary database connection.